# Статическая и динамическая линковка в XCode

Tags: xcode, c

Доброго времени суток! 
Заранее прошу прощения, если вопрос покажется глупым)
Вопрос не совсем связан с Objective-С. Проекта серьёзного как такового нет) обычная университетская лабораторная работа в которой выполняются действия над массивами. Проект Command Line Tool, написан на Си. Никаких своих библиотек, как очевидно, нет. Однако используются некоторые заголовочные файлы из стандартной библиотеки Си (libc). Так вот, сам вопрос в том, как делать статическую и динамическую линковку проекта в XCode? Заранее спасибо.

Всем огромное спасибо! Особенно [[@Stanislaw Pankevich](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich)](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich). Всё решилось вот этим http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Feb/msg00699.html

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, XCode это какая-то IDE в MAC-е.

А просто `cc` из командной строки Вашу программу не собирает?

Comment: @avp, да, Xcode - это IDE, и в вопросе тут явно речь идёт про интеграцию его Xcode'а средствами, без коммандной строки. Я вроде в ту сторону ответил ;)

Comment: @avp, да, правильно. сс из командной строки, как я понимаю, программу собирает. В папке с main.c появляется файл a.out. Вызывая его в терминале запускается данная программа. Однако преподаватель хочет, чтобы ему продемонстрировали динамическую и статическую линковку. Судя по размерам exec файла (14 кб), происходит динамическая линковка. Т.е. сама библиотека, так сказать, не включается в проект и при запуске на пустой ОС программа не выполнится.

Comment: Не знаю, какой компилятор в маке, но для статической сборки (по умолчанию, конечно, динамика) попробуйте 

    cc main.c -Wl,-static

(в gcc таким образом (-Wl,-флаг-линкера) передаются ключи в ld).

Поскольку мак это все-таки \*nix(?), то надеюсь, что линкер никто там не менял.

Вообще, читайте `man ld` и `man cc`

--

Кстати, заголовочные файлы (.h, которые Вы упомянули в вопросе) это просто текст (буковки), который вставляется вместо `#include ...` в текст программы *перед* компиляцией и к линковке (статической/динамической) они отношения не имеют.

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich, скинула запрос

Не вижу запроса. Точно послали?

Comment: в маке clang, он во многом совместим по флагам с gcc и даже представляется им (gcc в маках последних версий это ссылка на clang)

Comment: Решили вопрос, оказывается это вообще было не про Xcode, а про виндовс и Visual C... ))

Зато я хороший простой пример скрафтил для обоих типов библиотек: https://github.com/stanislaw/Hashcode ;)

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, посмотрел Вашу ссылку....

Static linking of user binaries is not supported on Mac OS X.

это сильно.

Обратите внимание: user binaries!!!

Comment: @avp, у меня кончились комментарии - уже начал удалять. Гляньте ещё одну ссылку на Apple QA (там же в моём ответе).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, прочитал. Спасибо, буду знать.

    try building crt0.o for yourself. Obviously, we won't support such an endeavor.

практически то же самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В надежде, что правильно понял Ваш вопрос, отвечаю про статическую линковку:

Вам нужно в главном таргете вашего проекта найти вкладку: Build phases, а потом Link Binary With Libraries - нажимаете "+" и добавляете .a-файл вашей библиотеки.

С динамической линковкой я пока что не сталкивался, поэтому не подскажу.

---

Наверное, Вам известно, что в Xcode есть пресет для создания C/C++ библиотеки (вторая картинка). Я предполагаю, что Вы могли бы создать каркас для вашей библиотеки по этому шаблону и добавить его в ваш проект (это предположение - я сам пока не пробовал делать такое).

**Обновлено позже**

На картинке 3 вы видите, что при создании шаблона Xcode предлагает выбрать static/dynamic - я не пробовал, но предполагаю, что это правильный способ сделать библиотеку средствами самого Xcode, а не командной строки.

---

**Обновлено ещё позже**

По поводу статической линковки libc я успел уже задать свой вопрос: [How / is it possible to build C “Hello world” program entirely static (OS X, Clang)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181467/how-is-it-possible-to-build-c-hello-world-program-entirely-static-os-x-cla), а потом нашёл похожий на него дубликат:

[Creating static Mac OS X C build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259249/creating-static-mac-os-x-c-build)

Оттуда есть ссылка на позицию Apple по данному вопросу (почему они не поддерживают статическую линковку системных библиотек):

[Technical Q&A QA1118
Statically linked binaries on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html).

---

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что Вы немного сами не понимаете, что Вам нужно. Я добавил ещё картинку, в которой видно, что Xcode учитывает static/dynamic. 

Что касается линковки a-файлов, это я ошибочно предположил, что у вас __уже есть a-файл вашей библиотеки__, и вы хотите его добавить в некий свой другой Xcode-проект. Если же вы создаёте С-библиотеку средствами Xcode (без командной строки), используйте вот эти самые шаблоны Xcode (скрины 2 и 3).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, как  понимаю, вы на 3-м скрине создаёте именно свою статическую библиотеку, да? libc.dylib, как я понимаю, динамическая библиотека, а статическая линковка выполняется со статическими библиотеками. Так вот вопрос в том, что можно ли как-то эту библиотеку "присоединить" к продукту, чтобы этот exec файл можно было запустить на абсолютно любом (в том числе и практически пустом) Маке? Просто в разделе Products у меня только exec файл, так как тип проекта Command Line Tool.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, Простите, если что, просто я немного провожу аналогию с Visual Studio. Там: "В настройках проекта в пункте Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library указать опцию, не содержащую “DLL” (в зависимости от Debug или Release версии). Можно убедиться, что библиотеки не линкуются динамически, запустив проект в студии и заглянув в окошко Modules." (взято из http://0xc0dec.org/2011/02/06/vs-runtime-static/) 
Так вот можно ли что-то подобное сделать в XCode?

Comment: @VAnya, прочитав пост по Вашей ссылке я, наконец, понял, чего Вы хотите, - я, конечно, отвечал на другие вопросы. Я сходу не знаю, как это сделать, но попробую поглядеть, самому стало интересно. Хороший вопрос))

Comment: Давайте ещё раз уточним: Вы хотите линкануть статически именно libc (скорее всего, это невозможно в принципе) к своему проекту, или вы хотите сделать свою библиотеку статической и подцепить её проекту Xcode?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, именно libc. Потому что создавать свою библиотеку в данном примере, как я думаю, смысла нет.
В таком случае, если это невозможно, то как же можно будет запустить exec-файл на другом компьютере? Эти библиотеки везде как-то "вшиты"?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, скинула запрос

Comment: @VAnya,  в ubuntu я сделал static вот так


    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/Tele2/stg/t2info$ gcc t.c
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/Tele2/stg/t2info$ gcc -o t-static t.c  -Wl,-Bstatic -static-libgcc -lc
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/Tele2/stg/t2info$ ll t-static a.out 
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 avp avp   8455 Mar  4 22:24 a.out*
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 avp avp 891895 Mar  4 22:24 t-static*


Видимо в маке примерно так же.

Comment: Скорее всего он хочет свою динамическую библиотеку линкнуть к какому-то тестовому проекту. Такая же проблема у меня сейчас!!! Не могу найти решения. Нашал только что нужно создать файл FileName.def и туда прописать функции, которые хочу линковать. Вот ссылки, может помогут:
http://qin.laya.com/tech_coding_help/dylib_linking.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002257-BAJJBBHJ